# Strange FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, testng

this my project strucuture: 
[image]

and i found the next exception:

```
    aused by: org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.FlowModelBuilderException: Couldtion at class path resource [WEB-INF/flow/consultaDeutes/consultaDeutes.xml]
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.xml.XmlFlowModelBuilder.init(Xml        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.DefaultFlowModelHolder.assembleF.java:86)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.DefaultFlowModelHolder.getFlowMo:61)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.doInit(Flow        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flow/consultaDeutes/consultaDeutes.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
            at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.ja        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDova:98)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.xml.XmlFlowModelBuilder.init(Xml        ... 50 more
```

What is wrong here? i'm pretty desperate ty.

```
@Override
     protected FlowDefinitionResource getResource(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
         FlowDefinitionResource resource = resourceFactory.createResource("consultaDeutes.xml");
         Assert.assertNotNull(resource);
         return resource;
     }

    /*[src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flow/consultaDeutes/consultaDeutes.xml]*/

    @Test
    public void testFlowShouldEnterStartState()
    {
     this.startFlow(context);
    // assertCurrentStateEquals("a_cargar_info");

    }
```

Comment: what's problem? `resource [WEB-INF/flow/consultaDeutes/cened because it does not exist`. I don't see this file on your image

Comment: Check the exception trace "WEB-INF/flow/consultaDeutes/cened" it is looking in to WEB-INF/flow/consultaDeutes and inside it it is looking in to cened. Does your project structure has "cened" as file/directory?

Comment: Did you try to refresh your project (right click -> refresh) and project clean?

Comment: How did you access the resource? code?

Comment: sorry copy & paste was wrong...

Comment: yes i show you the code.i'll try in many ways what i don't find the way out...maybe is some other thing ans i don't see.

Comment: did you use `consultaDeutes.xml` as parameter for `createResource()` or `src/.../ .xml`

Comment: Maybe the URL path should be `/WEB-INF/flow/consultaDeutes/consultaDeutes.xml` with `file:` as it is not a resource (not in WEB-INF/classes/)

Comment: WTF!!! you are right!! I've get a different exception now ! i'll find the context!! :) i really aprecciate your help, well everyone help.

Comment: Can you explain better in an answer, to culturize me. I'll accept your answer. ty.